# How many projects you know uses Velocity framework

Tags: velocity

Do you have idea how many sucessful projects used Velocity framework for developing their UI ?.The reason I am asking is Velocity is replaced in most of the cases by JSP tags, but in our product we still use Velocity frmaework.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually it's the other way around. People replace JSPs with Velocity. (Because of a better [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns)) The list of projects using Velocity is too long to list here. A big site that I know is using velocity is [joost.com](http://www.joost.com/).

Answer (score 1):

This [Powered By Velocity WIKI Page](http://wiki.apache.org/velocity/PoweredByVelocity) should give you an idea of just a  "few" projects that use Velocity in a way or another.

Answer (score 1):

> Do you have idea how many successful projects used Velocity framework for developing their UI ?

At least hundreds of them :).

On the *Powered by Velocity* page mentioned above, are listed just a "few" of them.

> The reason I am asking is Velocity is replaced in most of the cases by JSP tags, but in our product we still use Velocity framework.

I think Velocity is not "replaced" by JSP but it's an alternative. It's a very good and efficient alternative, as most users will find much easier to learn it than JSP.

Of course, there are other very good template engines too, but Velocity seems to have the simplest syntax so far, and it's performance is very good.

Answer (score 1):

I'd bet there are far more sites using velocity for ui rendering, email formatting etc behind corporate firewalls than we will ever know.  Its also embedded in other apache projects, and can also be used as a very clean code generator ... Much nicer than working with xslt/xpath.  My next project is jdo/stripes/velocity/gwt.